# IIS exclude specific host?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, rras

I have an IIS server running several websites. It is stationed behind an ISA server of which I do not have access. But I do have all of the defined websites (on port 80) routed to my server.

So I want to take down one website, say it's foo.bar.com and in its place setup a LAMP server instead using a VM software. It needs to run alongside all the existing websites and it should not interfere with them.

I have full control over my server, but not the ISA.
Is this possible? If so, how?

The OS is Win Server 2003 Standard with IIS6

Comment: You could just make it a WAMP server instead...

Comment: No, I couldn't. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many websites are running on the windows box?  are they setup with host headers or IP addresses?

If they're setup with IP addresses (i.e. each site has its own IP), then  its easy.  Have your LAMP box take over the IP of the website you wish to convert.

If it's a single IP & you have host header, then its not so good.  You really should be speaking to your ISA administrator. The only other way i can see it working is if you setup your own server to do reverse proxying & then forward the traffic to your LAMP or IIS server depending on the hostname.  Apache has a reverse proxy module, so you can do it right off your LAMP box.

Comment: Since ISA is handling the reverse proxy functionality, it's more important to know how ISA is connecting to the web site...  usually the publishing rule would be mapped to the published name, with an IP Address included to ensure the correct server is resolved...  You should really work with the ISA folks for this to work correctly...

Comment: I see. It's all using one IP and a multiple host headers so I guess that's a no-go for me :( ... But seriously, wouldn't adding another layer infront of IIS would make everything slow down? Because most of traffic is to the IIS, not my little Apache setup.

Comment: +1 It's a good answer though :)

Comment: Since it's a single IP and your only using host headers the only option would be to use the URL Rewriting Proxy services...  And yes, it would slow things down...  Depending on the load the slowness could be measurable...

Comment: will slow things down for sure.  This is why you need to speak to the person managing ISA

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible if you configure the IIS 6 server as a proxy server.  Managed Fusion has a [URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/) that can do transparent proxy that should be able to have the IIS server pull all requests from your LAMP server.

In the discussion forum of the URL Rewriter project is [an article](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=39331) that talks about doing something similar to your request; this article is about Apache on a localhost but shouldn't be much different for a remote Apache Server).

EDIT:  Keep in mind that using IIS as a proxy to a LAMP (or any other server) is incredibly wastful...  You should work with the ISA Admins to redirect the web publishing to the actual target server.

Comment: That seems like a workable approach. But isn't it in anyway possible to use the Routing infrastructure in Windows server to do it?

Comment: No way to use RRAS that I am aware of...